# Android OpenGLES Brown square

Tags: android, opengl-es

So I'm trying to learn openGLES 2.0 and create a textured rectangle. Apparently I didn't follow all the instructions and now I've ended up with just a odd color square.

heres my shaders.

```
final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.
        + "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;\n" // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
        + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
        //          + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.

        //          + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
        + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;     \n"   // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
        + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
        + "{                              \n"
        + "   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;\n"     // Pass the texture coordinate through to the fragment shader.
        // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
        + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
        + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
        + "}                                \n"; 

final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;       \n"     // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a
        // precision in the fragment shader.
        + "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;   \n"    // The input texture.

        + "uniform vec4 u_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the
        // triangle per fragment.
        + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;  \n" // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.

        + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
        + "{                              \n"
        + "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate); \n"
        + "}                              \n";
```

Here is the load texture function

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

And here is the drawFrame

```
        @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Set the background clear color to gray.
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_Texture");
    mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

    // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);

    // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
    // Draw the triangle facing straight on.
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, Fields.screen_width / 2, Fields.screen_height / 2, 0);
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, Fields.screen_width / 4, Fields.screen_width / 4, 0);
    drawTriangle(mTriangle1Vertices);
}
```

Any advice for getting rid of the wierd brown square and actually displaying the texture?

Edit: Here are the texture coordinates

```
public GL20Renderer(Context context) {
    final float[] triangle1VerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z,
            // R, G, B, A
            -1f, 1f, 0.0f,
            -1, -1, 0.0f,
            1f, 1f, 0.0f,               
            -1f, -1f, 0.0f,
            1f, -1f, 0.0f,
            1f, 1f, 0.0f,           
    };
    // Initialize the buffers.
    mTriangle1Vertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle1VerticesData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTriangle1Vertices.put(triangle1VerticesData).position(0);

    final float[] triangle1TextureCoordinateData =
        {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
        };
    mTriangleTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle1TextureCoordinateData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTriangleTextureCoordinates.put(triangle1TextureCoordinateData).position(0);
    this.context = context;
}
```

and here is the drawtriangle function

```
private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer aTriangleBuffer)
{
    // Pass in the position information
    aTriangleBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    int colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_Color");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4f(colorHandle, 0.0f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which now contains model * view * projection).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: Possibly you are not setting the texture co-ordinates properly and the entire square is being colored with the corner of the top-left texel of the texture. Post the code in drawTriangle or wherever you call glVertexAttribPointer

Comment: I thought that as well and tried changing it. But I didnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `drawTriangle` code doesn't set the texture co-ordinates anywhere. Add some code something like this:

```
triangle1TextureCoordinateData.position(mPositionOffset * 2 / 3);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        0, triangle1TextureCoordinateData);

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
```

Note you can set the stride to zero if your data is packed in the buffer.

Comment: Holy crap, There it is. I can't believe I missed that. Shouldnt it throw an error for something like that?

Comment: Generally OpenGL doesn't throw errors unless you do something really bad like causing a seg fault by passing an invalid memory address. It just silently fails and you have to check whether something went wrong by calling glGetError() or glGetShaderInfoLog() or glGetProgramInfoLog() etc. Although in this case I don't think an error would be logged because it's possible to create shaders with optional attributes that default to zero if you don't set them.

Comment: That makes things a fair bit difficult, but thank you.